# add data to rows under an added column?

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, dataset

I have a table where I would like to add a column and under that column an unique value for each row from top to bottom.

Something sort of like:

```
Mytable.Columns.Add("NewColumn");
```

then add strings "Row1","Row2","Row3","Row4" under NewColumn.

so result would be similar to

```
NewColumn-----ExistingColumn1-----ExistingCoulmn2
Row1----------Existingdata1.1-----Exisitingdata1.2
Row2----------Existingdata2.1-----Exisistingdata2.2
....
....
```

and so on.

Comment: Which database is it?  MS-SQL?  MySQL?

Comment: When you say "table", do you mean table in the database, or table in the client UI? In other words, do you want to add the actual data to the database, or just emulate the calculated column in your client code?

Comment: It is an xml loaded into a dataset i am diplaying with Datagridview. I basically would just like row headers but can't sdeem to figure it out. Insert data into a specific cell in a datgridview based on cloumn name and row index?